# how to manipulate the query string in vue.js using Vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue.js app that has a tagging component. I'd like to add a url components like https://thisdomain.com/some?tag_ids=3,7,11 where a user can add tag_ids by toggling the tags in the UI.

While this is working for maintaining the tag_ids in the app. I'd also like to have them render in the browser url so that if the url is shared, it looks the same. I am using vue-router and I'd like to add the tag_ids to the query string but not force a new route in the path. I have tried something like:

```
   this.$router.push({ path: '/', tag_ids: this.selectedTagIds })
```

and

```
   this.$router.replace({ path: '/', tag_ids: this.selectedTagIds })
```

But this is not working. Any idea how to manipulate the query params via this.$router?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `params`:

```
//navigation
this.$router.push({ name: 'some', params: { tag_ids: this.selectedTagIds } })

//route
{ path: '/some', name: 'some', component: Some }
```

Or, you can use `query` like this:

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/some', query: { tag_ids: this.selectedTagIds } })
```

Comment: Good one +!. I think `query` is what the OP seems to need.